# x86 iterate over a 2-byte word array

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

I'm writing a loop in an 8086 game using emu8086 and I want to iterate over word values but not bytes of an array declared like this;

```
player_fire  dw 320 dup(0)

; ...

mov  bx, offset player_fire
mov  cx, 320
fire_loop:
mov  ax, [bx+si]
inc  si
loop fire_loop
```

but I know that this is wrong. I also have problems writing to the ith element  whether I should reference it with  bx + si  or   bx + (2*si) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ith element is located at [base + 2*register].

That can't however be written directly before 80386 addressing modes. On 8086+ you can do it with:

```
 fire_loop:
  mov ax,[bx+si]
  add si, 2
  loop fire_loop
```

Comment: Another option is to simply increment the pointer, `add bx, 2`

Answer (score 0):

```
 fire_loop:
  mov ax,[bx+si];;mov to the next sell and put in ax
  add si, 2; inc si
  loop fire_loop;dex cx and loop
```